# how to run python script on a VM instance in Google cloud platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am developing a messenger app using WebSockets, I want to run the server script in a Linux VM instance and access it using the VMs public IP from the client script running from my and a friends system ( such that I and the friend can chat ) but how do I go about running a script on VM, am I supposed to make an app and deploy it to app engine and then somehow get that deployed app in the VM? I am really confused, do correct me if anything above if wrong, I am new to cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a virtual machine on Google Compute Engine is the most straightforward solution. This will allow you to set up a public IP, SSH to the VM, upload your script, and execute it in the terminal. Try the Linux quickstart [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux) to get started.

---

App Engine could work in this situation but is less suited. App Engine is a Platform-as-a-Service offering that scales compute resources up and down based on the number of concurrent HTTP requests that reach it. Those compute resources are:

1. ephemeral, meaning they won't have a consistent public IP to connect to.
2. intended to transactionally respond to HTTP requests, meaning they are not suited to running scripts the way a persistent VM would be.